# Calculating parasitic capacitance of serial zener diodes

Tags: capacitance, zener, series, parasitic-capacitance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpJyY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have 2 series zener diodes like these in the schematic.

Their capacitance is C=225pF

How do I calculate their equivalent capacitance so I can calculate my time constant?

Is it 225pF || 225pF or just C1+C2?

Comment: 1/((1/C1)+(1/C2)) = Ctot

Answer (score 1):

Diode capacitance often rated at some DC voltage such as 0V which decreases  reverse bias.

If it were two fixed caps of equal value the answer you should know for 2 series caps is 1/2 of C as @winny said

Cs = 1/((1/C1)+(1/C2))

If they were parallel then Cp=C1+C2